# Autocomplete in billing page

Tags: magento, autocomplete, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am using reduce checkout for my checkout. In magento by default for billing information page, autocomplete is disabled. I want to enable autocomplete="on" for billing page and shipping information pages. When I made a google on this, I came to know this can be done by  placing autocomplete="on" method="post" in both pages. I made as above in the paths of theme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml. But none of them worked. But in magento by default for registration page it works fine with out any autocomplete="on" in the form pages. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the cache before testing? Did you check the actual html output if the autocomplete attribute is missing?

Comment: yes. It displays the "autocomplete=on" method="post" attributes when we make inspect element of the billing form. But it is not working